# What's the proper boundary condition for this ODE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, asymptotics, boundary-value-problem

I want to obtain when $l=-1$ the asymptotic behavior at $x\rightarrow0$ or just the boundary condition at $x=0$ of the following eigen ODE system of 2 components $(\alpha,\beta)(x)$ defined for $x\in[0,\infty)$
$$
F_{l+1}\beta+m\alpha=\lambda\alpha\\
F_{-l}\alpha-m\beta=\lambda\beta
$$
where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue, $l$ is integer, $m(0)$ is finite, and $F_l\alpha=i(-\frac{d}{dx}-\frac{l}{x})\alpha$.

The purpose is to find the left boundary condition for the eigenvalue problem. I suppose for $l\neq0,-1$ it's all just Dirichlet as $\alpha(0)=\beta(0)=0$. But how to get the $l=-1$ or the similar $l=0$ case, which looks somewhat different?